# Is it possible to have different icons for adding web to homepage and splash screen?

Tags: html, manifest, progressive-web-apps

So, I was trying to add - add to home screen feature. So I want the icon which displays on homepage and the image the comes on splash screen to be different. And what if I don't want to show name on splash screen? Is this possible?

Comment: You may want to check first the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/). This [Adding a Splash Screen for Installed Web Apps in Chrome 47](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen) documentation will help you to know more about splash screens. The splash screen is generated dynamically from information held in the Web App Manifest and is a combination of the `name` and `background_color `properties, and the icon in the `icons` array that is closest to "128dp" for the device.

Answer (score 1):

@scripter The splash screen is constructed as a combination of the background color and the icon(s) defined in the web app manifest. The "Adding a Splash Screen..." post pointed out by @abielita describes some considerations regarding the proper icon size and other details; it is a very good read.

Comment: Was trying to help you out. Giving negative scores easily discourages people from answering questions.

Comment: sir, I didn't. I appreciate your help. :)